# How to access nested children with same name in XML using lxml in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, lxml

I'm trying to parse an XML file using "lxml" module in Python.
My xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <GEOMdata>
        <numEL>2</numEL>
        <EL>
            <isEMPTY>true</isEMPTY>
            <SECdata>
                <SEC>
                    <Z>10.00</Z>
                    <A>20.00</A>
                    <P>30.00</P>
                </SEC>
                <SEC>
                    <Z>40.00</Z>
                    <A>50.00</A>
                    <P>60.00</P>
                </SEC>
            </SECdata>
        </EL>
        <EL>
            <isEMPTY>false</isEMPTY>
            <SECdata>
                <SEC>
                    <Z>15.00</Z>
                    <A>25.00</A>
                    <P>35.00</P>
                </SEC>
                <SEC>
                    <Z>45.00</Z>
                    <A>55.00</A>
                    <P>65.00</P>
                </SEC>
            </SECdata>
        </EL>
    </GEOMdata>
</root>
```

I want to write a text file for each "EL" reporting isEMPTY value and a list of Z,A,P values. Despite the I/O I don't understand how to access this file. 
For the moment I wrote that code:

```
from lxml import etree
parser = etree.XMLParser(encoding='UTF-8')
tree = etree.parse("TEST.xml", parser=parser)

for ELtest in tree.xpath('/root/GEOMdata/EL'):
    print (ELtest.findtext('isEMPTY'))
```

and the output is correct:

```
true
false
```

Now I don't know how to access the children element Z,A,P "inside" ELtest.

Thanks for your kind help.

EDIT:
The desired output is a formatted file like this:

```
1
true
# Z    A    P #
 10   20   30
 40   50   60

2
false
# Z    A    P #
 15   25   35
 45   55   65
```

Comment: It's not clear what you need as output. Please provide an example.

Comment: Sorry about that, I just edited my post

Comment: You already know that you find all `<EL>` elements when you search for the XPath `/root/GEOMdata/EL` and for each of those, you know that the text of the `<isEMPTY>` element is output when you do `ELtest.findtext('isEMPTY')`. Now, when you combine these two bits of knowledge...

Comment: There's only one `<numEL>2</numEL>`  how do you want to get 2 values?

Comment: numEL is irrelevant in this context, but there are 2 different "EL" blocks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
from lxml import etree
parser = etree.XMLParser(encoding='UTF-8')
tree = etree.parse("_etree.xml", parser=parser)

with open("output.txt", "w", encoding="utf8") as f:
    e = tree.findall('GEOMdata/EL')
    for i in e:
        isEMPTY = i.find('isEMPTY')
        SECdata = i.findall('SECdata')
        f.write(isEMPTY.text+"\n")
        for y in SECdata:
            z = y.find("SEC/Z").text
            a = y.find("SEC/A").text
            p = y.find("SEC/P").text
            f.write("{} {} {}\n\n".format(z,a, p))
```

---

**output.txt:**

```
true
10.00 20.00 30.00

false
15.00 25.00 35.00
```

Comment: Thank you SO much! I'm a newbie to Python and you really helped me understanding the "find" and "findall" statements. Thank you again!

Comment: Great! I'm glad I could help you.

Comment: It seems that only the first "SEC" value is printed. I think that an additional "for" loop after "for y in SECdata:" is necessary. I solved using "iterchildren", i will edit the post by adding the solution.

Comment: I missed the last loop, you found the answer by yourself, that's the way! I wouldn't mind if you marked your answer as the correct one, honestly! GL

Comment: It doesn't matter, thank you. Without the correct "find" input I would never be able to find the solution!

Comment: 5 stars to you!

Answer (score 1):

Final solution of my question, (thanks to Pedro Lobito!) is:

```
from lxml import etree
parser = etree.XMLParser(encoding='UTF-8')
tree = etree.parse("_etree.xml", parser=parser)

with open("output.dat", "w", encoding="utf8") as f:
    e = tree.findall('GEOMdata/EL')
    for i in e:
        isEMPTY = i.find('isEMPTY')
        SECdata = i.findall('SECdata')
        f.write(isEMPTY.text+"\n")
        for y in SECdata:
            for k in list(y.iterchildren()):
                z = k.find("Z").text
                a = k.find("A").text
                p = k.find("P").text
                f.write("{} {} {}\n".format(z,a,p))
            f.write("\n")
```

Output file is:

```
true
10.00 20.00 30.00
40.00 50.00 60.00

false
15.00 25.00 35.00
45.00 55.00 65.00
```